# error while importing Matcher from spacy.matcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am trying to use spacy in order to get proper names from a text, but when I run the code I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L/Desktop/spacy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\L\Desktop\spacy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from spacy.matcher import Matcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.matcher'; 'spacy' is not a package
```

I installed spacy and its trained model with pip using

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Here is the code I am working on

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher


# load pre-trained model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# initialize matcher with a vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)


def extract_name(resume_text):
    nlp_text = nlp(resume_text)

    # First name and Last name are always Proper Nouns
    pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]

    matcher.add('NAME', None, *pattern)

    matches = matcher(nlp_text)

    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = nlp_text[start:end]
        return span.text


text ="some text"

fullName = extract_name(text)
```

can anyone help with this error.

Comment: Which spacy and python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.7.4 with spacy 2.1.8

Comment: okey. send your installed python packages list using pip freeze in terminal.? Are you doing it using virtualenv?

Comment: No I am not using virtualenv.
I got spacy==2.1.8 from pip freeze (the list is too long)

Comment: I tried only the first 2 lines and I got the same error on interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you called your file `spacy.py`, while you're also trying to use the package `spacy`. Never name your script the same as an existing module.

Solution: rename your file to something different (e.g. "main.py" or "app.py").